# Is it possible to run two TFLite models at the same time on a Flutter App? / make Teachable Machine recognize when an object is not present?

Tags: tensorflow, flutter, dart

I am using a Teachable Machine model which i trained to recognize some specific objects, the issue with it, however, is that it does not recognize when there is nothing, basically it always assumes that one of the objects is there. One potential solution I am considering is combining two models like the YOLO V2 Tflite model in the same app. Would this be even possible/efficient? If it is what would be the best way to do it?

If anyone knows a solution to get teachable machine to recognize when the object is not present that would probably be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved making a model ensemble: Train a classifier that learns to know if your specific objects are not in the visual space, and then use your detection model.

However, I really recommend you to upload your model to an online service and consume it via an API. As I know tflite package just supports well MobileNet based models.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just create another class called whatever you want(for example none) and put some non-related images in it, then train the model.
Now whenever there is nothing in the field, it should output none.